# php login system remember me style

Tags: php, remember-me, login-script

i wrote this code to start session in secure way

```
function sessionStart() {
    $session_name = 'sec_session_id'; // Set a custom session name
    $secure = false; // Set to true if using https.
    $httponly = true; // This stops javascript being able to access the session id. 

    ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1); // Forces sessions to only use cookies. 
    $cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params(); // Gets current cookies params.
    session_set_cookie_params($cookieParams["lifetime"], $cookieParams["path"], $cookieParams["domain"], $secure, $httponly); 
    session_name($session_name); // Sets the session name to the one set above.
    session_start(); // Start the php session
    session_regenerate_id(true); // regenerated the session, delete the old one. 
}
```

now i have a question if we have this session_regenrate_id then our session id will change when this will execute in each page??if i regenerate id for session how should i use cookie for user who wanted to be logged in for 1 month for example?
is this secure to increase $cookieParams["lifetime"] to 1 month for example?if no how should i achieve this for 1 month? i use ssl then i think my cookies are safe.

**Update**

another way that i go is storing session in database.

```
      <?php
    /**
     * PDO Session Handler
     * @author Daniel15 <dan.cx>
     *
     * This class is actually static, but since PHP doesn't support static classes, abstract is close
     * enough. You do not instantiate the class; you just call the static "init" method.
     */
    abstract class PDOSession
    {
            private static $db;
            private static $oldData;
            /**
             * Initialise the PDO session handler
             * @param PDO PDO instance to use for database
             */
            public static function init(PDO $db)
            {
                    self::$db = $db;
                    // Add the session handlers
                    session_set_save_handler('PDOSession::open', 'PDOSession::close', 
                                             'PDOSession::read', 'PDOSession::write', 
                                             'PDOSession::destroy', 'PDOSession::garbageCollect');
                    session_start();
            }

            /**
             * Session open handler
             * @param string Path to save session to
             * @param string Name of the session
             */
            public static function open($save_path, $session_name)
            {
                    // Nothing
                    return true;
            }

            /**
             * Session close handler
             */
            public static function close()
            {
                    // Nothing
                    return true;
            }

            /**
             * Session load handler. Load the session
             * @param string Session ID
             */
            public static function read($session_id)
            {
                    // Load the session data from the database
                    $query = self::$db->prepare('
                            SELECT data
                            FROM sessions
                            WHERE session_id = :session_id');
                    $query->execute(array(':session_id' => $session_id));

                    return $query->fetchColumn();
            }

            /**
             * Session save handler. Save the session
             * @param string Session ID
             * @param string Data to save to session
             */
            public static function write($session_id, $data)
            {
                    /* Try to update the existing session. If we can't find one, then create a new one. If you
                     * are using MySQL, this can be done in a single INSERT statment via INSERT ... ON 
                     * DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE. Remove the UPDATE and edit the INSERT to do it this way.
                     * See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html
                     *
                     * This does two queries so you can use any DBMS.
                     */

                    $query = self::$db->prepare('
                            UPDATE sessions
                            SET data = :data, last_activity = :last_activity
                            WHERE session_id = :session_id');
                    $query->execute(array(
                            ':session_id' => $session_id,
                            ':data' => $data,
                            'last_activity' => time()));

                    // No session to update? Create a new one
                    if ($query->rowCount() == 0)
                    {
                            self::$db
                                    ->prepare('
                                            INSERT INTO sessions
                                                    (session_id, data, last_activity)
                                            VALUES
                                                    (:session_id, :data, :last_activity)')
                                    ->execute(array(
                                            ':session_id' => $session_id,
                                            ':data' => $data,
                                            'last_activity' => time())
                                    );
                    }
            }

            /**
             * Session delete handler. Delete the session from the database
             * @param string Session ID
             */
            public static function destroy($session_id)
            {
                    self::$db
                            ->prepare('
                                    DELETE FROM sessions
                                    WHERE session_id = :session_id')
                            ->execute(array(':session_id' => $session_id));
            }

            /**
             * Session garbage collector. Delete any old expired sessions
             * @param int How many seconds do sessions last for?
             */
            public static function garbageCollect($lifetime)
            {               
                    self::$db
                            ->prepare('
                                    DELETE FROM sessions
                                    WHERE last_activity < :min_time')
                            ->execute(array(':min_time' => time() - $lifetime));
            }
    }
?>
```

now for this how should i create cookies in this situation?

Comment: Sessions alone wont work to enable a "Remember me" system. They have a short lifetime and will get cleaned up on the server.

Comment: thanks question improved in second situation

Answer (score 2):

#### You need to use cookies...

Now we need to make this checkbox do something. Namely, when checked, remember the users username and place it in the username field on each of their corresponding visits to the login page. To do so, I decided to use cookies. I couldn’t use the “ID_my_site” username cookie that I set above, as this was being killed each time the user logged out. The solution was to create an additional cookie named “remember” which also stored the username, like so:

```
$year = time() + 31536000;
setcookie('remember_me', $_POST['username'], $year);
```

Above we have added this additional cookie, lasting for a year, so that when a user logs in it creates an additional cookie that holds the users username. However, at the moment, it is not being used. Changing:

```
<input type="text" name="username" maxlength="40">
```

to:

```
<input type="text" name="username" maxlength="40" value="<?php
echo $_COOKIE['remember_me']; ?>">
```

in our login form will now store this username into the text field for future visits:

We are not finished yet though. Currently, the code is storing this information for every user. We want it to remember only those users who specifically request this functionality. To do this, we run a simple check before we create the additional cookie. This check looks to see if the remember me checkbox has been checked, and only creates our new cookie if it has. Like so:

```
if($_POST['remember']) {
setcookie('remember_me', $_POST['username'], $year);
}
elseif(!$_POST['remember']) {
    if(isset($_COOKIE['remember_me'])) {
        $past = time() - 100;
        setcookie(remember_me, gone, $past);
    }
}
```

The above code also handles the scenario where a cookie is present, but the user has identified that they no longer want to be remembered, by setting any existing cookies to a time in the past, essentially killing them.

Read more [here](http://www.downwithdesign.com/web-development-tutorials/adding-remember-feature-php-login-script/)...

Comment: As I understood it, the intent is keep someone logged in, this will only remember the username for the login box.

Comment: is it safe to store usernames in cookies?should'nt i add some hash to it or sha512 this value?

Comment: Usernames are fine I guess. But no passwords. Just give the session information in the cookies in an encrypted way and store the session on the server. That's the best method.

Comment: i dont think this is a good idea because maybe some user fill his or her username and password in your site from coffenet or bus or school and then hacker can easily use this password by reading cookie.

Comment: you mentioned this line in tutorial which is a security hole i think 
setcookie('Key_my_site', $_POST['pass'], $hour);

Comment: NO! Storing that Username and Passowrd information is a **HUGE SECURITY HOLE** and it is stored in plain text. I have never said that. What I said was, storing the session information, like the session hash, in the cookie, so that when you visit the site again, you will be logged in, only on that computer.

Answer (score 2):

Going into detail of how this works will take more time than I have to write it all. But I should be able to give you a high level summary of how this works.

PHP sessions are time-limited. They will get cleaned up after a period of time. You can extend that time in the PHP config, but not long enough to be effective.

So what needs to be done is the creation of an alternative login route. This has to be implemented carefully, as doing this carelessly can open up security loopholes.

The concept can be summarized as creating a one time use, unique, cookie that is associated with a user and can be used as an alternative to a username and password.

This cookie should be unique, generated with random data, and stored in association with the user. It should be time limited (it will expire if not used in a week or two) and regenerated once its used.

Changing user data like email/password should require the users password.

Site should use SSL to make cookie interception much more difficult.